# Angular Material Stepper Component styling with css variables

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I've installed Angular 16 along with the Angular Material library. I've used these CSS variables to style the stepper component (simplified):

```scss
--mat-stepper-header-icon-background-color: transparent;
--mat-stepper-header-icon-foreground-color: red;
--mat-stepper-header-done-state-icon-background-color: transparent;
--mat-stepper-header-done-state-icon-foreground-color: red;
--mat-stepper-header-selected-state-icon-background-color: red;
--mat-stepper-header-edit-state-icon-background-color: red;
--mat-stepper-header-label-text-color: red;
--mat-stepper-header-optional-label-text-color: red;
--mat-stepper-header-selected-state-label-text-color: red;
--mat-stepper-header-error-state-label-text-color: red;
--mat-stepper-header-error-state-icon-foreground-color: red;

--mat-stepper-header-label-text-size: 1.6rem;
--mat-stepper-header-label-text-weight: 600;
--mat-stepper-header-selected-state-label-text-weight: 700;
```

Initially, everything looked good. However, after I pushed the code to a remote branch and then fetched that branch on another device, the styles no longer work. I can't even find those variables when inspecting the  component in the dev tools. It's as if they never existed. I suspect that something may have been updated in the project, possibly the version of the Material library.

I fetched version 16.1.x of the Material repository and tried to search through the files for these variables, but I couldn't find anything. It's perplexing.

Now, here's my question: Did these variables ever exist? What was the version of the Material components when they were used, and why might they have been removed?

Comment: I re-read my question and I think I didn't make it clear that those variables with `--mat-stepper-***` prefix were copypasted from devtools (they are not mine, they are angular's)